# How do I create a form and connect it to a post type? So, when any one submits the form, it gets published as a post?

Tags: wordpress, forms, elementor

I want to create a form, which is more like a social media. Where people can write and attach documents, then after the submitting the form, it automatically gets published in a specific post type.

I am using WordPress, with Elementor and Ultimate Membership Pro (From Codecanyon).

Trying to have a community page where users/public can share things...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.